# Not able to delete RabbitMQ cluster on Google Cloud

Tags: rabbitmq, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have created RabbitMQ cluster via "click-to-deploy" from Google Cloud.

I tried deleting that cluster, but failed. I then manually deleted load-balancers and VM instances created, but still the cluster is hanged in half deletion stage.

```
Message received 
-----------------
Your RabbitMQ cluster failed to delete
Jul 4, 2014, 9:58:45 PM
queueRamNodes: DELETING
queueDiskNodes: DELETING
rabbitMq-Queue-Nodes: DELETE_FAILED
Error deleting Load Balancer : Required 'WRITER' permission for 'projects/<projectname>'
rabbitMq-WebManagement: DELETE_FAILED
Error deleting HttpHealthCheck : Required 'WRITER' permission for 'projects/<projectname>'
statsNode: DELETING
rabbitMq-All-Nodes: DELETE_FAILED
Error deleting Load Balancer : Required 'WRITER' permission for 'projects/<projectname>'
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the health check (rabbitmq-webmanagement-00131) may be causing the cluster deletion to fail.

Try deleting all rabbitmq-* target pools, forwarding rules and health checks using Google Developer Console -> Compute -> Compute Engine -> Network load balancing. Then try to delete the cluster and hopefully it will succeed.